# How to mock multiple functions of a typescript class?

Tags: function, unit-testing, typescript, mocking, jestjs

Suppose, I have a typescript class

*a.ts*

```
export class A {
    constructor() {
         this.__functionA()
    }

    private __functionA(){
        this.__functionB()
    }

    private __functionB(){
    }

}
```

Now, I have some *tests* for my *Class*

```
import { A } from "./a"

describe("Class A",() => {

    it(`__functionB should Have been called`,() => {

        A.proptotype.__functionB = jest.fn()
        A.proptotype.__functionA = jest.fn()

        let instance = new A()

        expect (instance.__functionB).toHaveBeenCalled()
        expect (instance.__functionA).toHaveBeenCalled()

    })
})
```

the tests fail with an error

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Now, when I mock only the `__functionA` of **Class**`A` and run my assertions against only that *function*, i.e. `expect (instance.__functionA).toHaveBeenCalled()`, my test pass. Why so?

And How can I mock more than one **functions** of a **Class**?

Correct me, if I am doing something wrong here.

**N.B.:-** *I am using **jest** to run my tests*.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer,

I just had to replace

```
A.proptotype.__functionB = jest.fn()
A.proptotype.__functionA = jest.fn()
```

with

```
jest.spyOn(A.proptotype,__functionA)
jest.spyOn(A.proptotype,__functionB)
```

and everything works fine.

Hope, this helps someone.